# Taking audio input from microphone in browser and extracting features

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, audio-recording

What would be the best library-programming language to capture raw audio input from microphone in the browser and then be able to extract features from it?

I am aware that I can use `getUserMedia()` in JavaScript to capture audio, but can it working with that audio easy using JavaScript or I should look in a different direction?

Comment: could you please tell little more about what do you want to do with the recorded audio?

Comment: The answer is, "yes", it is easy to work with audio.  Perhaps you could tell us specifically what you want to do so we can provide more details

Comment: There are different APIs available which have a lot of *features*. But since you don't tell us what *features*, we can't lead you to anywhere. Also *easy* is an opinion-based word.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is!

The easiest one to use is **[Microphone.js](https://github.com/stderr/microphone.js/tree/master)**

> #### USAGE
>
> To instantiate the main Microphone object, use the create function:

```
require(['microphone'], function(microphone){
 var Microphone = microphone.create();
 });
```

> To activate voice processing, use the on function:
>   
> `Microphone.on();`
>   The primary usage of microphone.js is through the addCommand function. This takes two main arguments: patterns, which is assumed to be an array of regular expressions, and the callback, which is the code that will be run if any of the patterns specified match the voice input:

```
Microphone.addCommand({
    patterns: [new RegExp('dog', 'i')],
    callback: function() {
      alert("no, cats!");
    }
});
```

> The callback also receives two arguments: the current Microphone instance, allowing the user to inspect the currentTranscript and other relevant information; and the matched CommandString, which exposes the matched string, and the args, which is an array of the words following the matched string. This allows you to do things like:

```
Microphone.addCommand({
    patterns: [new RegExp("display", "i")],
    callback: function(mic, command) {
      $("#" + command.args[0]).show();
    }
});
```

> Thus, if you said "display foo", the DOM element with an id of foo would be shown (presuming you are using jQuery, of course).

There is also the [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html), which is more complex but also has more features.

The [`getUserMedia()`](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro) method is still the best way to do this, in my opinion, feel free to choose!